# VBA Macro For-each loop to find string "x" and display differences between sheets for other values

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

i have 2 worksheets with 7 columns in the same order, i am trying to match them and show the breaks and matches between the 2 sheets.

So I have been able to identify the difference and highlight them blue using VBA, but now i want to show the differences in for example the department "sales".

This code shows the differences in the 2 sheets:

```
For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet2).UsedRange
If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then        
    mycell.Interior.Color = vbRed
    difference = difference + 1

End If
Next
```

How do i loop through each row in the worksheet to see if that row contains "sales" and then for all those rows that contain "sales" display the total number of matches and differences?

I would like to apply this to the other departments as well such as "Marketing", "I.T".

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: "How do i loop through each row in the worksheet" - you have two worksheets, which one is _the worksheet_?

Comment: @FreeMan sheet 1 contains the old  data and sheet two contains the new data, i have highlighted the differences in the second sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your departments are specified on the first column, you could achieve that by creating a dictionary of differences. Please check the code below as an example and modify it to fit your needs.

```
Sub Problem()

Dim shtSheet1 As String
Dim shtSheet2 As String
Dim departmentColumn As Long

shtSheet1 = "Sheet1"
shtSheet2 = "Sheet2"
departmentColumn = 2

'Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'Commented the code above, the below two lines of code will replace it.

Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

dict.Add "Sales", 0
dict.Add "Marketing", 0
'Add as many types of differences you want to keep track of

    For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet2).UsedRange
    If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then
        mycell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        difference = difference + 1

        'Supposing the first column is the one with the information about the department
        If dict.Exists(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Cells(mycell.Row, departmentColumn).Value) Then
            dict(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Cells(mycell.Row, departmentColumn).Value) = dict(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Cells(mycell.Row, departmentColumn).Value) + 1
        End If

    End If
    Next mycell

MsgBox "Errors: " & difference & vbCrLf & "Marketing: " & dict("Marketing") & vbCrLf & "Sales: " & dict("Sales")

Set dict = Nothing

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Changed the code above to: 1 - Let you set the department column on the departmentColumn variable, now set to 2 (second column); and 2 - Fix your Scripting reference problem. Before using the code, please follow the steps below:

Go to your Macro Editing Window and select Tools > References:
[image: ReferenceMenu]

Select the option Microsof Scripting Runtime as in the window below, check it and click the Ok button.

[image: ReferenceAdding]

This steps will enable your macro to access scripting libraries.

Comment: Tony, if you are still in trouble with this and the code is not what you are looking for, post a comment and I will come back to it, check if fits your needs.

Comment: thanks for the help!! unfortunately the department is in the second column as the first has the ID for that row  of data. I am new to VBA so when i try the code i am getting issues with "set dict =..." as it says it is not defined. Thanks again

Comment: Tony, please check the answer again, it has been edited to help you with that.

Comment: Abe, thank you! it does work, however it seems to give me a count greater than what is true. i.e i have a test work sheet which has 6 headers, now marketing and sales only appear for 3 entries however the code is giving me a count of 24 when it should be 18...any idea?

Comment: Maybe you have columns with spaces that will count as cells in the "UsedRange" in the first sheet, but in the second sheet they are empty?